# will it be hoisted when a variable is transformed in jest test case?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, testcase

I was developing and testing Array.isArray module.

**isArray module**

```
export isArray function (arg) {
  if (Array.isArray) {
    return Array.isArray(arg);
  }
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
}
```

**isArray TC**

```
describe('isArray test', () => {
  describe('[native] test', () => {
    test('[] => true', () => {expect(isArray([])).toBe(true); });
  });

  describe('[native not exist] test', () => {
    delete Array.isArray;
    test('[] => true', () => {expect(isArray([])).toBe(true); });
  });
});
```

It seems that the delete Array.isArray phase is hoisting.
so, all TC are not native to the isArray module.
describe phase is hoisiting in TC?
please tell mw how to make it unaffected delete phase.

Comment: Hoisting is only relevant to declarations, there is no such mechanics for anything else. I am unclear what the problem is here, though - how do you determine that `delete` always runs first?

Comment: Also note that the content of a describe callback, as opposed to test/it/afterX/beforeX callbacks, runs at *test definition time*, not at test execution time.

Comment: test definition is executed in execution time. and delete Array.isArray phase is executed in definition time. i think this problem is definition and execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Hoisting" isn't the correct term here – you're just deleting a global property without ever resetting it to the original value, and that will persist between test cases.

The simplest fix is to manually reset the object:

```
describe("[native not exist] test", () => {
  test("[] => true", () => {
    const originalIsArray = Array.isArray;  // Grab original function
    delete Array.isArray;  // Remove it
    expect(isArray([])).toBe(true);  // Test
    Array.isArray = originalIsArray;  // Undo the removal
  });
});
```

Comment: Just mentioning - for tests, this is probably fine. If removal and re-adding is needed to be more correct (although god knows why that would be), you can do `original = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, property); delete target[property]; /* later */ Object.defineProperty(target, property, original);`. That will preserve the property descriptors of the property.

Comment: I deleted Array.isArray in the third describe statement, 
but when I run the test case, Array.isArray is deleted in the first statement as well.
If i delete it from the describe statement, it is executed asynchronously and then the test statement is executed.

Comment: If I apply your opinion, would I have to delete and restore every test case?

Comment: You could use `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()`, for instance.